# Prevent last change in parent window when jquery colorbox iframe window open

Tags: jquery, colorbox

when colorbox iframe window loading, parent page go backs to default page ie., changes made in parent page is lost (here changes are hide some part and display some part in parent page).

Comment: I can not show code.

Comment: parent window having frameset.. is that problem using frameset!!